# how to use crosswalk project in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, crosswalk-runtime

i am facing much difficulty using crosswalk project with eclipse , is there any plugin for eclipse .

gone through their documentation which seems too complicated:

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/getting_started/windows_host_setup.html#Install-Ant

has anyone idea how to integrate and use it with eclipse

anyway i found one plugin for eclipse at :
https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-developer-tools-eclipse-plugin

i followed below link:
https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-developer-tools-eclipse-plugin

to create cross walk hello world project fro android .

now it creates blank project

```
facedetection
--index.html
--manifest.json
```

there are no java file and other .
how can i run this project ??.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is a HTML5 applications. You just need to edit these two files. Please refer to https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/getting_started/build_an_application.html.

After you edit your code. You can generate the android apk as follow:
Export Crosswalk Application

```
1.In Eclipse menu: Select "File->Export"
2.Select "Crosswalk/Export Crosswalk App" then click next
3.Input the required information then click "Finish" button
```

The you can install the apk to your device.

Comment: After Export I am getting alert message like "The crosswalk app has been exported successfully!". But .apk file was not found at exported path directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Eclipse and Android SDK already, you can install [Crosswalk-Eclipse-plugin](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-developer-tools-eclipse-plugin) into your Eclipse. It supports to create an empty Crosswalk Application and to package it. More details refer to the link.

Comment: i create a project using your guide .
now it creates blank project 
facedetection
--index.html
--manifest.json

there are no java file and other .
how can i run this project ??.